# Euclidean division of polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $f, g \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ be two polynomials with $g \ne 0$. There exist $q, r \in \mathbb{F}[x]$ s.t. $f=qg + r$ and $\deg\ r < \deg\ g$.

I actually have the answer but need a bit of guidance in understanding the answer.

Proof:
We first prove the unique existence of $q, r$ such that $f = qg+r$ and $\deg\ f \geq \deg\ g$.

Let $f = a{_m}x^m$ and $g = b{_n}x^n$ where both $a{_m}$ and $b{_n} \ne 0$.

So the base case is where $m - n = 0$. Therefore $m = n$, the quotient $q = a{_m}/b{_n}$ and $ r = f-qg$. $q$ is well defined and the coefficient $x^m$ in $r$ vanishes, and where $\deg\ r \lt m = \deg\ g$

So first question is, what do they mean when they say the coefficient of $x^m$ disappear? I understand that we defined the degree of g is greater than degree r, and I suspect they divide out or something of that sort. But can someone clarify that?

So that was the base case. The induction step is defined:
$m = n + d$ where $d \gt 0$. Let $f' = f-(a{_m}/b{_n})x^{m-n}g$. Notice $\deg\ f' \lt \deg\ f$.

So my second question is why how did the author come to define $f' = f-(a{_m}/b{_n})x^{m-n}g$?

He then goes on:

by induction there exists $q', r$ with $\deg\ r \lt \deg\ g$ and $f'= q'g + r$. Therefore
$f = f' + (a{_m}/b{_n})x^{m-n}q=(q'+(a{_m}/b{_n})x^{m-n})g+r$.

So at this point I have become totally lost on the induction step. Can anyone offer any guidance?

Comment: Uniqueness: if $f=q_1g+r_1=q_2g+r_2$ then $(q_1-q_2)g=r_2-r_1$. The rhs has degree $<\mbox{deg} g$. So the only way the latter can hold is if $r_2-r_1=0=q_1-q_2$.

Comment: "Vanishes", in additive contexts, usually means "equals zero". Because one generally does not write terms of a sum equal to zero, when one does a calculation or modification to an object that makes a term become zero, it is reasonable to say the term has vanished.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This will probably make more sense if you work with actual examples. Another good thing to do is review the concepts behind long division and the division algorithm for *numbers*, since the idea is barely any different *at all* between number and polynomial settings - I stress this highly. When you do long division with numbers in base ten, you're essentially doing *polynomial* long division with the number as a "polynomial" in the "variable" $x=10$, since every number has a decimal representation of the form $a_n10^n+\cdots+a_2100+10a_1+a_0$, though with each $0\le a_i<10$.

Suppose you have $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. What would you *personally* do to find one of the "closest" (in a certain sense) polynomial multiple of $g(x)$ to that of $f(x)$? Let me give you an explicit example,

$$f(x)=3x^3+1,\quad g(x)=2x+1.$$

First, let's understand what notion of closeness we have in mind. We want the closeness of two polynomials to be determined by how many leading coefficients they share. So, to obtain a first approximation, what can we multiply $g(x)$ by so that the resulting leading coefficient matches that of $f(x)$? Why, $\color{Red}{\frac{3}{2}x^2}$, of course. We see that their difference is given not by a cubic but a quadratic:

$$f(x)-\color{Red}{\frac{3}{2}x^2}g(x)=(3x^3+1)-\left(3x^3+\frac{3}{2}x^2\right)=-\frac{3}{2}x^2+1.$$

We can go further and decompose $-\frac{3}{2}x^2+1$. Multiply $g(x)$ by $\color{Green}{-\frac{3}{4}x}$ so that its leading coefficient matches that of $-\frac{3}{2}x^2+1$. For their difference we obtain

$$\left(-\frac{3}{2}x^2+1\right)-\left(\color{Green}{-\frac{3}{4}x}g(x)\right)=\frac{3}{4}x+1.$$

Finally, we must multiply $g(x)$ by $\color{Blue}{\frac{3}{8}}$ for its leading coefficient to match $\frac{3}{4}x+1$, and

$$\left(\frac{3}{4}x+1\right)-\color{Blue}{\frac{3}{8}}g(x)=\frac{5}{8}.$$

Hence, we have

$$f(x)=\left(\color{Red}{\frac{3}{2}x^2}\color{Green}{-\frac{3}{4}x}+\color{Blue}{\frac{3}{8}}\right)g(x)+\frac{5}{8}.$$

Notice that, at each stage, we have reduced our problem of "approximating" a degree $n$ polynomial with multiples of $g(x)$ with that of approximating a degree $n-1$ polynomial with multiples of $g(x)$, and this is where induction comes into play. To go from one level of the induction to an already-assumed case, we take a difference by a "first-approximation" which reduces the degree of what we're trying to approximate. (Going from $f(x)$ to $f(x)-(a_m/b_n)x^{m-n}g(x)$, of lesser degree.)

Review!

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_division
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_long_division

Answer (score 0):

Let $\rm\:\ell(f) =\:$ leading term of $\rm\:f,\:$ and $\rm\:d(f)=deg(f).\:$ $\rm\: d(g) < d(f)\:\Rightarrow\: \ell(g)\mid \ell(f),\:$ so $\rm\:\ell(f) = cx^k \ell(g).\:$ Therefore $\rm\:f' \,:=\, f\,-\, cx^k g\:$ has $\rm\  d(f') < d(f)\ $ because the subtraction cancels $\rm\,\ell(f).\,$

Thus an element $\rm\:r\:$ of $\rm\:R = f - g\, \Bbb F[x]\:$ of least degree must have
$\rm\:d(r) < d(g)\:$  (for otherwise, as above, we deduce $\rm\:r' \in R\:$ has $\rm\:d(r') < d(r),\:$ contra minimality of $\rm\:r\,).$

Comment: Geez, I feel bad posting so many questions as you seem to always answer them all. But my problem is $f′=f−((a{_m}/{b_n})x^m−n)g$ where does they author get that?

Comment: Actually the scaled $g$ i do see. its the portion where $f' = f$ is part of my confusion. I'm not how this equation was derived.

Comment: @shosh It's as a said, it comes from scaling $\rm\,g\,$ by $\rm\,\ell(f)/\ell(g) = cx^k\,$ so to create a multiple of $\rm\,g\,$ with the same leading term as $\rm\,f,\:$ so it will cancel $\rm\,\ell(f)\,$ when subtracted from $\rm\,f.\:$ This yields the descent: given any element $\rm\:h\in f-g\,\Bbb F[x]\:$ with $\rm\,d(h) > d(g)\,$ there exists one of smaller degree, viz. $\rm\,h' = h - \ell(h)/\ell(g)\: g.\ \ $